# Local collection types not allowed in SQL statements - when using IN keyword on personal TABLE

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, plsql

I must pass a list of number in input into a procedure. I defined a table of numbers instead of a varray as found on internet, but I still get the error:

> PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements

DEFINITION OF TYPE:

```
TYPE liste IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

DEFINITION OF PROCEDURE:

```
PROCEDURE myproc(
IN_COMM_ID IN liste);
```

PROCEDURE'S BODY:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT (ID) 
FROM
     MESSAGGE
WHERE
     ID IN IN_COMM_ID;
```

What should I do to correctly perform the iteration into the where condition?

Comment: try placing prenthesis around  `IN_COMM_ID` . Just like `ID IN (IN_COMM_ID);`

Comment: i'm using oracle sql.
@MuhammadWaheed i tried but i doesn't work, while if i try (select id_comm from comm) it works

Answer (score 0):

In sum, the `PLS-00642` error you're getting is telling you that you have a locally-defined collection type in your SQL statement.  It appears that the issue is with the array in your PL/SQL where you defined the TYPE, as below:

```
TYPE liste IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

To avoid the `PLS-00642`, the collection will need to be defined at the schema level; therefore, you would need to define the varray table as a real table, using Oracle DDL with the CREATE TYPE syntax.

Comment: i defined into the package declaration and then used into the package body. is it incorrect?

Comment: No create a physical object at schema level

Comment: doing like this, i get:
Errore(119,36): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: incoerent data type: expected NUMBER, obtained NMSD_MESSAGES.LISTE.
(i self translated the error message, so i'm sorry if it's not correct)